# NuGet Dependency Framework Targeting not working when packaging using the .csproj

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a NuGet .nuspec that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>XXXXXXXXX</id>
        <version>1.0.0-alpha</version>
        <authors>XXXXXXXXX</authors>
        <owners>XXXXXXXXXXX</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</description>
        <copyright>XXXXX</copyright>
        <dependencies>
            <group>
                <dependency id="Dependency1" version="1.0.0" />
            </group>
            <group targetFramework=".NETFramework3.5">
                <dependency id="Dependency2" version="3.9.71" />
            </group>
            <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0">
                <dependency id="Dependency3" version="4.0.30" />
                <dependency id="Dependency4" version="4.0.30" />
                <dependency id="Dependency5" version="4.0.30" />
                <dependency id="Dependency6" version="4.0.30" />
            </group>
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src=".XXX.Net35\bin\Release\XXX.dll" target="lib\net35" />
    </files>
</package>
```

When I package the NuGet package with the nuspec via:

```
nuget pack XXXXXX.nuspec
```

Everything is good, the dependency groups are all there. If I package with the csproj like:

```
nuget pack XXXXXX.csproj
```

The dependencies are all lumped into one target rather than in groups. I really want the functionality of using the $id$ and $version$ variables with the ability to do dependency groups based on target framework.

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you go to the directory that has your `.csproj` file and execute `nuget spec` to create a `.nuspec` file based on your `.csproj`. Investigate it and make sure it looks as you want, customize it for various target frameworks, then `nuget pack XXXXXX.csproj` to have it build and respect the `.nuspec`.

Comment: I've been on vacation but will look into this after the holidays. Thanks for the response!

Comment: nuget spec just made a blank nuspec file. It put me back to square 1. We ended up writing a powershell script that set the version via the -version param in the pack command.